# New window calling C# method on close

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms, user-controls

I open a new window like this whent he DoButton is pressed:

```
//mainform.aspx
protected void DoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open('mypage.aspx?action=hello', null, 'height=500,width=900,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true); 
    }

protected void IWillClose(){ //more code here...}
```

mypage.aspx has 2 buttons: Confirm and Cancel. Whenever any of those buttons is pressed the window is closed.

**The question:** is there any way to call `IWillClose();` inside `mainform.aspx` whenever this new window is closed?

Comment: yes, create a new c# class (.cs file) in your project, and define some pubic `static` methods, such as: `public static void IWillClose()` so that you can call these methods anywhere in your project (in this case call it in `Confirm` and `Cancel` click event)

Answer (score 0):

To verify that the page is about to be closed, you can use a javascript event, and to call a server side code use the PageMethods like the code below.

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode(){
   PageMethods.IWillClose();
}
```

Do not forget you need to add the `EnablePageMethods = "true"` in your ScriptManager